# List of hosts in Varnish

Tags: cache, varnish

I'm running a VPS with multiple different websites, and Varnish in front for caching. 
However, some websites should not be cached. 
Instead of making individual rules for each website, I would like to make a general "DON'T CACHE" list, which is linked to some rules. Possible?

In the following, I've sketched what I would like: a list of websites (ACL syntax) in the VCL configuration which should not be cached.

```
list cache_blacklist {
 "domain1.com";
 "domain2.com";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host ~ cache_blacklist) {
    return(pass);
  }   
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.http.host ~ cache_blacklist) {
    return(hit_for_pass);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice question, I was thinking of the exact same thing, I thought of some kind of array option, but the list is much better. What's wrong with the code you gave here? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The list would need to be explicitly specified as 'acl', instead of 'list', but anyway I'm not sure varnish allows you to compare anything but against the client's IP address with an ACL anyway, so this wouldn't work even if the syntax was correct.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. "list"s doesn't exist in Varnish, so it throws a syntax error. I tried like JamesHannah suggested, to use `acl cache_blacklist {}` however, ACL will only match with `client.id` - not `req.http.host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing : you don't need to set a vcl_fetch rule if the condition depends on the **request**. Everything will be handled in vcl_recv.

vcl_fetch rules are only needed when condition depends on the server **response**.

HTTP Host being in the request...your vcl_fetch rule is actually useless.

Now that you don't need to tell "which domains should not be cached" twice, just use a single condition in vcl_recv like this :

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "domain1.com" || 
        req.http.host == "domain2.com") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

Note that you can also use regexp...not sure about which is the best...

Comment: Yes this is the way to go